# Serialize List<Tuple<String, String>> to Attributes

Tags: c#, serialization

I want to serialize List of tuples to XML Attributes. For example:

```
List<Tuple<String, String>> attributes = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();
attributes.Add(New Tuple("att1", value1"));
attributes.Add(New Tuple("att2", value2"));
```

It should appear as:

```
<Root att1="value1" att2="value2">
</Root>
```

Edit:
I have a class like this which I am serializing using XmlSerializer:

```
public class Root
{
     List<Tuple<String, String>> attributes = new List<Tuple<String, String>>();

     //other attributes and elements exist in this class
}
```

Is there an easy way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: What are you having trouble with and what have you tried?

Comment: You should define the elements inside the class with the [`XmlAttributeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeattribute.aspx).

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name and number of attributes before hand. So It has to be some sort of undefined elements in an array/list etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect since `New` is capitalized in VB not C#.

Please read the documentation for [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and try to work through the examples.

Here is an example:

```
var attributes = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
attributes.Add(Tuple.Create("att1", "value1"));
attributes.Add(Tuple.Create("att2", "value2"));

var document = new XDocument();
var root = new XElement("Root");
document.Add(root);

foreach(var node in attributes.Select(x => new XAttribute(x.Item1, x.Item2)))
{
    root.Add(node);
}

Console.WriteLine(document); // <Root att1="value1" att2="value2" />
```

Edit:

To use the `XmlSerializer` use attributes:

```
[XmlType("Root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlAttribute("attr1")]
    public string Attribute1 { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("attr2")]
    public string Attribute2 { get; set; }
}
```

Or you'll need to implement `IXmlSerializable` for the dynamic attributes.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the name and number of attributes before hand. So It has to be some sort of undefined elements in an array/list etc.

Comment: Then XDocument would probably provide the simplest usage. Does this need to be both serializable and deserializable?

Comment: Yes, it needs to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: See if [XML Serialize dynamic object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7501846/xml-serialize-dynamic-object) works for you.