# XML serialization without defining types

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Is there any way to build a generic method for XML serialization and deserialization that doesn't require a bunch of gymnastics including pre-defining types using something like XmlInclude?  The code that I need to build cannot rely on pre-defined types.  I'm assuming Reflection could be used here, but I can't find an adequate solution.  The ones I've tried from NuGet each have limitations:

- Polenter seems to produce unusable output that cannot be deserialized
- Global, Netfx requires type definitions ahead of time
- Bender is beautiful but doesn't seem to support objects embedded within the object being serialized
- XSerializer and JsonFX are what I need on the serialization side but the output won't deserialize

The standard XmlSerializer won't work for obvious reasons (pre-defined types, XmlInclude, etc).

A simple example of what I need to serialize and then deserialize:

```
    public class c1
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public object obj { get; set; }
    }

    public class c2
    {
        public string city { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        c1 class_1 = new c1();
        c2 class_2 = new c2();
        class_1.name = "david";
        class_2.city = "chicago";
        class_1.obj = class_2;

        string xml = <insert here>;
        Console.WriteLine("XML: " + xml);

        c1 deserialized = new c1();
        deserialized = <insert here>;
        Console.WriteLine("City: " + ((c2)c1.obj).city);
    }
```

Does something like this even exist?

Comment: Does it have to be xml? maybe json?

Comment: Yes, I need a solution for XML.  I am using Newtonsoft for JSON (and it works beautifully).

Comment: I'm not really understanding your question, could you please me more clear?

Comment: Yes, I want a serializer and deserializer that doesn't force me to pass in type parameters and doesn't require me to use XmlInclude.  Please see XSerializer and JsonFx's XML serialization capabilities - they work great - but they just won't deserialize using the standard deserializer.  The reason that part is important is because other developers will be using the serialized output, and they may use the standard XmlSerializer.  For reasons I won't go into here, I cannot use the XmlSerializer for serialization on my end.

Comment: Serialization won't be a problem with something cast as object but deserialization will because the deserializer will not know what type to use. So it will have the xml for c1.obj but it will not know what type to instantiate since c1.obj is of type object. Best it could do on deserialization is a dynamic or expando. You could write the type info to the xml file so the deserializer knows what type to use but that's pretty dirty. I'm actually working on adding object support to Bender right now so I'm curious about your use case. I might be misunderstanding your question too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "not defining types".  If it's an object your code is working with, it has a type.  The easiest thing to do would be to write your code to work against ISerializable - then it can work with *any* serializable type - even those that your code isn't aware of at build time.  Alternatively, if you are working with dynamic objects (object's whose members are defined at runtime) check out this question for an example of making an ISerializable DynamicObject:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7501960/518955

Comment: Thanks - I'm aware of that.  That's not the solution I need.  The solution I need is what I've asked for above.